# Можно ли условию указать диапозон(e.keyCode)?

Tags: javascript

```
    document.querySelector('.input4').onkeypress = (e) => {
                         if (e.keyCode === 48 || e.keyCode === 49 ||e.keyCode===50||e.keyCode===51||e.keyCode===52||e.keyCode===53 || e.keyCode === 54 ||e.keyCode === 55 || e.keyCode === 56 ||e.keyCode===57){
       document.querySelector('.out2').innerHTML = false;
           } else {
        document.querySelector('.out2').innerHTML = true;
  }

     };
```

Comment: Свойство `keyCode` уже deprecated - его стоит использовать **только** как фоллбэк (если в юзерагенте не реализовано более новое `code`. Похоже, оно отсутствует только в IE и Edge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode<=57
```

Comment: Тут надо не через него делать, скорее всего.